# MongoDb Create Repository Pattern with new Async methods

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

```
public class MongoDbRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntityBase
{
    private IMongoDatabase database;
    private IMongoCollection<T> collection;

    public MongoDbRepository()
    {
        GetDatabase();
        GetCollection();
    }

    private void GetDatabase()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(GetConnectionString());
        database = client.GetDatabase(GetDatabaseName());
    }

    private void GetCollection()
    {
        collection = database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }

    private string GetDatabaseName()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MongoDbDatabaseName");
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MongoDbConnectionString").Replace("{DB_NAME}", GetDatabaseName());
    }


    public async Task<IList<T>> SelectAllSync() 
    {
     //Add _id that is unique for each document
     var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$exists", true));
     var people = await collection.Find<T>(filter).ToListAsync<T>();

        //Search methods
        var result1 = await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name)
                                .Aggregate()
                                .Match(x => x.last_name.Equals("Hall")).ToListAsync();


        var result2 = collection.FindAsync<T>(Builders<T>
                            .Filter.Eq(x => x.last_name, "Grammer")
                            , new FindOptions<T> { Comment = "TEST" }
                            , CancellationToken.None);

        var result3 = await collection.FindAsync<T>(
                           Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("dealership_name", "D-PATRICK NISSAN"),
                           new FindOptions<T> { Comment = "TEST" },
                           CancellationToken.None);



        return (IList<T>)people;
    }

    public Task Insert(T entity)
    {
        var result = collection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
        return  result;
    }

    public async Task<DeleteResult> Delete(T entity)
    {
        var deleteResult = await collection.DeleteOneAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(s => s._id, entity._id));
        return deleteResult;
    }

    public async Task<IList<T>> SearchFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var result = await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name)
                                .Aggregate()
                                .Match(predicate).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<IList<T>> GetById(ObjectId id)
    {
        var result = await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name)
                                .Aggregate()
                                .Match(x => x._id.Equals(id)).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<UpdateResult> Update(T entity)
    {
        if (entity._id == null)
            await Insert(entity);
```

> // Added list of string values for dealer_code

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("dealer_code");
        var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
             Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(s => s.dealer_code, entity.dealer_code),
             Builders<T>.Update.AddToSet(list[0], entity.dealer_code)
                                      );

        return result;
    }
}
```

I have problem with Update method. It gave me :

> "The serializer for field `'dealer_code'` must implement `IBsonArraySerializer` and provide item serialization info."

What does it mean ? How can I fix that?

Comment: dealer_code type is string.

Comment: Also, I don't see any reason you would need to do entity.ToBsonDocument() or get serializationInfo. "dealer_code" is always going to be the ElementName, since that's what you are passing in.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class MongoDbRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntityBase
{
    private IMongoDatabase database;
    private IMongoCollection<T> collection;

    public MongoDbRepository()
    {
        GetDatabase();
        GetCollection();
    }

    private void GetDatabase()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(GetConnectionString());
        database = client.GetDatabase(GetDatabaseName());
    }

    private void GetCollection()
    {
        collection = database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }

    private string GetDatabaseName()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MongoDbDatabaseName");
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MongoDbConnectionString").Replace("{DB_NAME}", GetDatabaseName());
    }


    public async Task<IList<T>> SelectAllSync() 
    {

        //var filter = new BsonDocument("dealer_code", new BsonDocument("$exists", true));
        //var people = await collection.Find<T>(filter).ToListAsync<T>();

        //Search methods
        var result1 = await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name)
                                .Aggregate()
                                .Match(x => x.last_name.Equals("Hall")).ToListAsync();


        var result2 = collection.FindAsync<T>(Builders<T>
                            .Filter.Eq(x => x.last_name, "Grammer")
                            , new FindOptions<T> { Comment = "TEST" }
                            , CancellationToken.None);





        return (IList<T>)result1;
    }

    public Task Insert(T entity)
    {
        var result = collection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
        return  result;
    }

    public async Task<DeleteResult> Delete(T entity)
    {
        var deleteResult = await collection.DeleteOneAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(s => s._id, entity._id));
        return deleteResult;
    }

    public async Task<IList<T>> SearchFor(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var result = await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name)
                                .Aggregate()
                                .Match(predicate).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<IList<T>> GetById(ObjectId id)
    {
        var result = await database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name)
                                .Aggregate()
                                .Match(x => x._id.Equals(id)).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<UpdateResult> Update(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,T entity) 
    {
        if (entity._id == null)
            await Insert(entity);

        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("dealer_code");

        var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
                                Builders<T>.Filter.Where(filter),
                                Builders<T>.Update.Set(x=>x.dealer_code, entity.dealer_code));

        if (result.IsAcknowledged)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally it begin to work  when I changed Update.Set() instead of Update.AddToSet()

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you're trying to call `$addToSet` on something that is not a set:

```
// ... 
Builders<T>.Update.AddToSet("dealer_code", entity.dealer_code)
// ...
```

But as you explained in the comment, `dealer_code` is of type `string`. You can only add something to a set if the element is a set, for instance a `string[]` or a `List<string>`. It's not perfectly clear what you want to achieve, but you might try changing `string dealer_code` to `List<string> dealer_codes`.

Comment: I have already changed List<string>  to get dealer_code, but method UpdateOneAsync not updated anything on MongoDb

Comment: Unfortunately, I see a lot of issues in your code, we should probably fix them one-by-one. Do I understand correctly that the exception is no longer thrown? What do you mean by 'changed `List<string>` to get `dealer_code`'? Have you changed the type of `dealer_code`? Can you post your class declaration?

Comment: You'll have to change `public string dealer_code` to `public List<string> dealer_code`. The modified code you have posted in your question doesn't make sense, because the list isn't part of the class...

Comment: I want to change only one field that have one value.                          public class Neoline : IEntityBase
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
      
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string dealer_code { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Finaly I found where I made mistake - it was because I tried to set value using AddToSet which is for list of objects . I had to use only Update.Set for one field . Thanks